# CsvParser Stream Closed Error

Tags: csv, groovy, ioexception

all.  I'm trying to parse a CSV file using CsvParser, but I get an IOException: Stream closed error after reading in line 57 (of ~6500).  Does anyone know what could be causing this?  Here is a code snippet and the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/ groovy

package csvTest

@Grab ('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def csvFile = new File("file.csv").withReader {
    CsvParser.parseCsv(it)
}

csvFile.each {
    println it
}

Caught: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader.getNextLine(CSVReader.java:245)
    at au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader.readNext(CSVReader.java:212)
    at au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader$readNext.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvIterator.hasNext(CsvIterator.groovy:72)
    at csvTest.CsvTest.run(CsvTest.groovy:12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CsvParser` is lazy, so reads rows as they are requested (rather than loading them all into memory.

The `withReader` call closes the `Reader` once the Closure is finished.

So when you try to do `csvFile.each`, the stream is closed.

This should work:

```
new File("file.csv").withReader {
    def csvFile = CsvParser.parseCsv( it )

    csvFile.each {
        println it
    }
}
```